# Phonegap Build Facebook Plugin Irregularities on First 2 Loads

Tags: facebook, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

OK, I'm stuck.   I'm on JQuery 1.9.1, JQuery Mobile 1.3.1, and Phonegap Build (currently running Phonegap 2.5.0).  I'm also using Phonegap Build's Facebook plugin.

Now, the good part -- it works.  All of it.  You're probably wondering why I'm here then, right?

Well, when I deploy my app on a new device, Apple or Android, the Facebook plugin will not allow me to login on the first time I load the app.  Just the first time.  If I exit out, close the process, and re-run the app -- it lets me login.

Then, once I can login to Facebook, the app can't post to Facebook.  I have to close it and re-run it again.  So, now I'm on the 3rd load and it all works fine from then on out.

I'm at a loss.  It's a black box to me.  The logs show nothing.  No errors, no warnings.  I can't see anything different between the loads.  This has been confirmed on 2 iPhones and 2 Android phones and 1 Android tablet.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is happening or how to better diagnose / troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, this problem went away when I updated my local Facebook clients.  They're currently at 2.3 and the issue is gone.